# Failing a build in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Under certain conditions I want to fail the build.  How do I do that?

I tried:

```
throw RuntimeException("Build failed for some specific reason!")
```

This does in fact fail the build.  However, the log shows the exception:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.RuntimeException java.lang.String
```

Which is a bit confusing to users.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

You can use the [`error`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal) step from the pipeline DSL to fail the current build.

```
error("Build failed because of this and that..")
```

Comment: Do you know if that message is stored in a variable like BUILD_NUMBER or JOB_NAME, etc...?

Comment: @PRF Why would it? When the build fails, the pipeline is over. Where would you then use that variable?

Comment: To use that message in mail or chatroom notifications

Comment: Just use `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}` `${env.BUILD_URL}` and `${env.JOB_NAME}`

Comment: A variable store could be used in the `post{fail{...}}` pipeline step.

Comment: Using error produces the following exception for me:

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Build failed because of this and that... ]`

Is nobody else having this issue when using error()?

Comment: @Eddie I'm very sure you have some sort of syntax error in your pipeline code.

Answer (score 13):

I have shown below different ways of error handling for declarative approach:

`failfast` in parallel pipeline

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55459?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Achangehistory-tabpanel

If a user has a Declarative Pipeline script with parallel stages, and they set `failFast true` for those stages, if one of the stages fails then the build is immediately aborted.

NOTE: `sh 'false'`  --> Can fail the stage

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             failFast true
             parallel {
                  stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        sleep 5
                        sh 'false'
                        echo 'stage A Ended' //will not execute because of above sh return

                    }
                }
                stage('stage B') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage B started'
                        sleep 10
                        echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
                 stage('stage C') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage C started'
                        echo 'stage C Ended' //May complete before Stage A fails
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

When `failFast true` it terminates the parallel tasks.

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage A)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage B)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage C)
[Pipeline] echo
stage A started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage B started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage C started
[Pipeline] echo
stage C Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] sh
+ false
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage A
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage B
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
Stage "final stage sequential" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

When "failFast false" it still continue executes other parallel tasks.

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage A)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage B)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage C) (hide)
[Pipeline] echo
stage A started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage B started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage C started
[Pipeline] echo
stage C Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] sh
+ false
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage A
[Pipeline] echo
stage B Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
Stage "final stage sequential" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

[Try-catch block in Jenkins pipeline script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003788/try-catch-block-in-jenkins-pipeline-script)

In declarative style of pipeline, so you must not use try/catch blocks (which are for Scripted Pipelines),
The key is to put try...catch in a script block in declarative pipeline syntax. Then it will work. This might be useful if you want to say continue pipeline execution despite failure (eg: test failed, still you need reports..)

NOTE: sh 'invalid command'  --> Can fail the stage even though it is part of script.

```
script {
  try {
      sh 'do your stuff'
  } catch (Exception e) {
      sh 'Handle the exception!'
  }
}


    try {
        sh 'might fail'
        echo 'Succeeded!'
    } catch (err) {
        echo "Failed: ${err}"
    } finally {
        sh './tear-down.sh'
    }


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             failFast true
             parallel {
                  stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        sleep 5
                        script {
                              try {
                                  sh 'I_AM_NOT_VALID_CMD'
                              } catch (Exception e) {
                                  sh 'EVEN_I_AM_INVALID_2_FAIL_THIS_BUILD!'
                              }
                        }
                        echo 'stage A Ended' //will not execute because of above sh return
                    }
                }
                stage('stage B') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage B started'
                        sleep 10
                        echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
                 stage('stage C') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage C started'
                        echo 'stage C Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}

Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage A)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage B)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage C)
[Pipeline] echo
stage A started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage B started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage C started
[Pipeline] echo
stage C Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ I_AM_NOT_VALID_CMD
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling@tmp/durable-5fc28a9a/script.sh: line 1: I_AM_NOT_VALID_CMD: command not found
[Pipeline] sh
+ 'EVEN_I_AM_INVALID_2_FAIL_THIS_BUILD!'
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling@tmp/durable-5e73fa36/script.sh: line 1: EVEN_I_AM_INVALID_2_FAIL_THIS_BUILD!: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage A
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage B
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
Stage "final stage sequential" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218554077-How-to-set-current-build-result-in-Pipeline

```
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'  //Should be inside script
This will not stop the executions.
```

[How to manipulate the build result of a Jenkins pipeline job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221836/how-to-manipulate-the-build-result-of-a-jenkins-pipeline-job)
by design, "result can only get worse, else set is ignored" -> @see setResult() @ https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/213363d387736874f1d14d83e57347f757f3ed4f/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java#L462-L466

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             failFast true
             parallel {
                  stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        sleep 5
                        script {
                            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        }
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage A Ended'
                    }
                }
                stage('stage B') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage B started'
                        sleep 10
                        echo 'stage B wakeup'
                        script {
                            currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                        }
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
                 stage('stage C') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage C started'
                        echo 'stage C Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}


Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage A)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage B)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage C)
[Pipeline] echo
stage A started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage B started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage C started
[Pipeline] echo
stage C Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
RESULT: FAILURE
[Pipeline] echo
stage A Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] echo
stage B wakeup
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] echo
RESULT: FAILURE
[Pipeline] echo
stage B Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
The complete run!
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

[How to throw exception in jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718785/how-to-throw-exception-in-jenkins-pipeline)

Throwing exception is not smooth output.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             failFast true
             parallel {
                  stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        sleep 5
                        script {
                            throw new Exception()
                        }
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage A Ended' //will not execute because of above sh return
                    }
                }
                stage('stage B') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage B started'
                        sleep 10
                        echo 'stage B wakeup'
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
                 stage('stage C') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage C started'
                        echo 'stage C Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}

Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage A)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage B)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage C)
[Pipeline] echo
stage A started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage B started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage C started
[Pipeline] echo
stage C Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.Exception. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage A
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage B
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
Stage "final stage sequential" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Also:   org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution.cancel(CpsBodyExecution.java:253)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.BodyExecution.cancel(BodyExecution.java:76)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStepExecution.stop(ParallelStepExecution.java:67)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$ResultHandler$Callback.checkAllDone(ParallelStep.java:147)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.steps.ParallelStep$ResultHandler$Callback.onFailure(ParallelStep.java:134)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsBodyExecution$FailureAdapter.receive(CpsBodyExecution.java:361)
        at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ThrowBlock$1.receive(ThrowBlock.java:68)
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.Exception
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectNew(StaticWhitelist.java:271)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onNewInstance(SandboxInterceptor.java:174)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$3.call(Checker.java:200)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedConstructor(Checker.java:205)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.constructorCall(SandboxInvoker.java:21)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:12)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:97)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor188.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:370)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:93)
    at 
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

[How to throw exception in jenkins pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718785/how-to-throw-exception-in-jenkins-pipeline)

```
node { try { error 'Test error' } catch (ex) { echo 'Error handled' } }  //node has to be replaced with scripts
```

`error` can make the parallel pipeline stages to stop executing it.

The below '`unstable`' command is similar to setting currentBuild.result = '`UNSTABLE`'.

This will not stop the executions.

```
script {
        unstable 'unstable'
}


pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             failFast true
             parallel {
                  stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        sleep 5
                        script {
                            error 'Test error'
                        }
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage A Ended' //will not execute because of above sh return
                    }
                }
                stage('stage B') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage B started'
                        sleep 10
                        echo 'stage B wakeup'
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
                 stage('stage C') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage C started'
                        echo 'stage C Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}




Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
[Pipeline] parallel
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
[Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage A)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage B)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (stage C)
[Pipeline] echo
stage A started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 5 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage B started
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 10 sec
[Pipeline] echo
stage C started
[Pipeline] echo
stage C Ended
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage A
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
Failed in branch stage B
[Pipeline] // parallel
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
Stage "final stage sequential" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Test error
Finished: FAILURE
```

---

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-catcherror-code-catch-error-and-set-build-result

```
catchError {
        sh 'might fail'
    }
```

This is equivalent to setting `currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'`

This will not stop the executions.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
         stage('Validate Fail fast') {
             failFast true
             parallel {
                  stage('stage A') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage A started'
                        sleep 5
                        script {
                            catchError {
                                sh 'might fail'
                            }
                        }
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage A Ended' //will not execute because of above sh return
                    }
                }
                stage('stage B') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage B started'
                        sleep 10
                        echo 'stage B wakeup'
                        echo "RESULT: ${currentBuild.result}"
                        echo 'stage B Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
                 stage('stage C') {
                    steps {
                        echo 'stage C started'
                        echo 'stage C Ended' //will not execute because of above stage fail
                    }
                }
             }
         }
         stage('final stage sequential') {
             steps {
                 script {
                     echo "The complete run!"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
}


    Started by user admin
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on Jenkins in /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Validate Fail fast)
    [Pipeline] parallel
    [Pipeline] { (Branch: stage A)
    [Pipeline] { (Branch: stage B)
    [Pipeline] { (Branch: stage C)
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (stage A)
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (stage B)
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (stage C)
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage A started
    [Pipeline] sleep
    Sleeping for 5 sec
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage B started
    [Pipeline] sleep
    Sleeping for 10 sec
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage C started
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage C Ended
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] script
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] catchError
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] sh
    + might fail
    /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/ErrorHandling@tmp/durable-2b5ebe28/script.sh: line 1: might: command not found
    [Pipeline] }
    ERROR: script returned exit code 127
    [Pipeline] // catchError
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // script
    [Pipeline] echo
    RESULT: FAILURE
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage A Ended
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage B wakeup
    [Pipeline] echo
    RESULT: FAILURE
    [Pipeline] echo
    stage B Ended
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // parallel
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (final stage sequential)
    [Pipeline] script
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] echo
    The complete run!
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // script
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    Finished: FAILURE
```

---

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to use certain methods/class you may get a similar message:

> org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.RuntimeException java.lang.String

Typically it is followed by a link to the Scripts Approval page in your Jenkins (which you can update if you are an admin).

For example from my own Jenkins:

> Scripts not permitted to use method org.w3c.dom.Element setAttribute java.lang.String java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method org.w3c.dom.Element setAttribute java.lang.String java.lang.String

The text **Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.** should be a link you can follow to the Jenkins Script Approval Page.
It's URL is typically:

```
http://<Jenkins URL>/scriptApproval/
```

Or should be accessible via: **Jenkins** -> **Manage** -> **In-process Script Approval**

On this page you can approve that scripts can use these method/classes.

However you should just be able to throw an **Exception** - I can do this without needing to do a script approval.

For example within my Pipeline groovy script:

```
throw new Exception('Some error text')
```

This output in the Jenkins build console:

```
java.lang.Exception: Some error text
at WorkflowScript.processProjectsToUpdate(WorkflowScript:106)
at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
```

This outputs quite a long stacktrace, the first line:

*at WorkflowScript.processProjectsToUpdate(WorkflowScript:**106**)*

Line 106 should be the the line in your Pipeline groovy script where the Exception was thrown, which may be useful information to you.

If you are not interested in the stacktrace, as in other answers just use **error**:

```
error('Some error text')
```

This is mentioned in the Jenkins Pipeline documentation: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal

> error: Error signal Signals an error. Useful if you want to
>   conditionally abort some part of your program. You can also just throw
>   new Exception(), but this step will avoid printing a stack trace.

Answer (score -7):

How about `System.exit(1)` if the failing condition is met?

```
private void test(boolean status){
    if(!status){
       printReport();
       System.exit(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Do not do this. This will shutdown Jenkins entirely.