# How to manipulate the build result of a Jenkins pipeline job (back to 'SUCCESS')?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm having some trouble to manipulate the build result of a Jenkins pipeline. I've narrowed it down to the following issue: anyone know why the following Jenkins pipeline doesn't make the build result SUCCESS? Instead the build fails.

```
print "Setting result to FAILURE"
currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'

print "Setting result to SUCCESS"
currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
```

Comment: Have you tried doing the whole script inside single `node`?

Comment: Just tried that, but same behaviour.

Comment: why don't you keep it in a variable, and then set it once you are ready?

Answer (score 26):

I guess this is by design, "result can only get worse" in [setResult()](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/213363d387736874f1d14d83e57347f757f3ed4f/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Run.java#L462-L466):

```java
// result can only get worse
if (result==null || r.isWorseThan(result)) {
    result = r;
    LOGGER.log(FINE, this + " in " + getRootDir() + ": result is set to " + r, LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINER) ? new Exception() : null);
}
```

That's a bummer

Comment: The idea is to ignore results of jobs inside pipeline by setting Propagate to false

Comment: @MarcusUA how can I ignore result of a phase, not external job?

Comment: @VadimKotov ignore results for each job inside phase.

Answer (score 16):

For simplier answer, just get raw build, and set field directly:

```
currentBuild.rawBuild.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
```

Comment: This is the one which worked for me. A plugin (NUnit Publishing) was setting the stage result to "unstable" via the "build.setResult" method, so error catching wasn't working. Adding this to the end of the stage done the job.

Comment: yes, this is the one. it is a pitty that TextFinder plugin doesn't have this implemented, with it you can set build only to unstable, not_built or success...

Comment: you just saved me hours of tricking around. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

That's works and can be executed from another job!

```
import com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.model.Result

@NonCPS
def getProject(projectName) {
    // CloudBees folder plugin is supported, you can use natural paths:
    // in a postbuild action use `manager.hudson`
    // in the script web console use `Jenkins.instance`
    def project = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(projectName)
    if (!project) {error("Project not found: $projectName")}
    return project
}

project = getProject('foo/bar')
build = project.getBuildByNumber(2443)
// build = project.getBuild(project, '2443')

build.@result = hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS
// build.@result = hudson.model.Result.NOT_BUILT
// build.@result = hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE
// build.@result = hudson.model.Result.FAILURE
// build.@result = hudson.model.Result.ABORTED
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @metajiji's answer, you will need to approve the commands for `hudson.model.result` and `project.getBuildByNumber` in the main jenkins configuration

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using this

```
currentBuild.result = hudson.model.Result.FAILURE.toString()
```