# How to prevent rtMaven (Artifactory Plugin with Pipeline) from failing builds when tests are unstable

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

Given the following code using [rtMaven](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-MavenBuildswithArtifactory) and assuming there are test failures

```
try{
rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: '-B clean install '
}catch(e){
    println "test failures?"
}
```

the build status is set to FAILURE although the exception is caught. Is there any possibility to prevent this and setting to build to UNSTABLE only?

Currently I am doing

```
rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: '-B clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true'

if (manager.logContains(".*There are test failures.*")) {
    currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
}
```

but obviously this is a fragile workaround...

Comment: You could try manually setting the build status inside the catch block `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'`

Comment: @SergejLopatkin: unfortunately this does not work (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38735701/4945535): currentBuild.result can only get worse. If that value was previously FAILED and receives a new status SUCCESS through currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS' it will stay FAILED

Comment: Thanks for the information, that is new to me. I suggest you then use the maven flag `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true'` like in the first snippet.