# Exclude user from triggering Jenkins build webhooks

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm currently working on my Jenkins setup in combination with fastlane.

In my fastlane file I'm updating the version as well as the `CHANGELOG.md` and pushing this to git.

However by doing this another build will be triggered causing an infinite loop.
What I've tried to do is adding the option to `exclude users`. However this doesn't seem to work.

[image]

I'm fairly sure this will only work when you are using polling. However I'm using webhooks in my gitlab to trigger the builds and I don't want to change to polling.

Does anyone know how to achieve this while using webhooks?

Comment: do you use pipeline? how about adding some string to the git log and if you find it - skip build? try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140255/how-to-get-the-git-latest-commit-message-and-prevent-the-jenkins-build-if-the-co/41161825#41161825

Comment: You don't say how you've configured user exclusion. You could perhaps also try path exclusion (i.e. don't build if `CHANGELOG.md` is altered).

Comment: @Amityo I use the normal build interface (not sure what it is called) and I don't want the build to show up as aborted/canceled

Comment: @ChristopherOrr I've configured it with the git plugin. However this only seems to work when you are using polling. Doesn't seem to work with web hooks. I believe the same goes for path exclusion

Comment: There is an open PR for this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/pull/1135