# Can a Jenkins job be aborted with success result?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative pipeline, using a multibranch job and a Jenkinsfile, can the job be **aborted** with a `success` exit code rather than a `failure` exit code?

In the below stage, I basically check if the commit that started the job contains "ci skip", and if it does I want to abort the job.

Using `error` aborts the job but also marks it as such (red row). I'd like this job to be marked with a green row.

```
stage ("Checkout SCM") {
   steps {
      script {
         checkout scm
         result = sh (script: "git log -1 | grep '.*\\[ci skip\\].*'", returnStatus: true) 
         if (result == 0) {
            error ("'ci skip' spotted in git commit. Aborting.")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit:**

Instead of the above, I am now trying to simply skip all stages in case the git commit contains "ci skip". My understanding is that if the result in `expression` is `false`, it should skip the stage...

```
pipeline {
    environment {
        shouldBuild = "true"
    }
    ...
    ...
    stage ("Checkout SCM") {
        steps {
            script {
                checkout scm
                result = sh (script: "git log -1 | grep '.*\\[ci skip\\].*'", returnStatus: true) 
                if (result == 0) {
                    echo ("'ci skip' spotted in git commit. Aborting.")
                    shouldBuild = "false"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    stage ("Unit tests") {
        when {
            expression {
                return shouldBuild
            }
        }
        steps {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so the way to get this to work is not with the `environment` directive but rather to use the `parameters`directive.

That is, adding `parameters` at the top of the `pipeline`:

```
parameters {
      booleanParam(defaultValue: true, description: 'Execute pipeline?', name: 'shouldBuild')
   }
```

When checking for the git commit, if it contains "ci skip" I change the value of `shouldBuild`:

```
env.shouldBuild = "false"
```

Then in `expression`:

```
expression {
    return env.shouldBuild != "false" 
}
```

And that's it. In case the git commit contains "ci skip" the stages are skipped and the job finishes with `SUCCESS`.

Comment: You should be able to access parameters with the `params` global so you also have the type available. You can then just do `return parameters.shouldBuild`

Comment: Thanks @mkobit, so it's `params.shouldBuild` or `parameters.shouldBuild`?

Comment: Also, should `env.shouldBuild` also change then to `params.shouldBuild` when I change its value?

Comment: So it's definitely not `parameters.shouldBuild`. "parameters" doesn't exist. But, after changing the return to what you suggested using `params`, I guess it thinks the value of `shouldBuild` is still "true" because it did not skip the stages...

Comment: Good catch with the `parameters`, that was my fault when posting from my phone. If I look at the `/pipeline-syntax/globals` on my Jenkins, I see the global `params` variable which says _Exposes all parameters defined in the build as a read-only map with variously typed values._. All `env` values get coerced into `String` type.

Comment: So, I think you should be abel to do `return params.shouldBuild`. `env.shouldBuild` will also be the `String` value of your parameter, so that will be `"true"` or `"false"` instead of the `boolean` typed value of `true` or `false`. I'm fairly confident with this, but I discover new and interesting strangeness with Jenkins pipelines daily.

Comment: Weird. Maybe I'll play with it again some time later... I'm. Not sure why it expression was true when it shouldn't have been, following your suggestion. Hmpf...

Comment: Awesome! I've been searching the internet for hours and this is, without a doubt, the simplest (and functional) way to do what I want. You, sir, are going places!

Comment: Why is the parameter even needed -- you're just setting an env var based on the commit message.

Answer (score 3):

If you are launching an error, it's not possible to change the status to `SUCCESS` because [a build result can only get worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221836/how-to-manipulate-the-build-result-of-a-jenkins-pipeline-job#answer-38321558).

Anyways, I implemented the ci-skip functionality by using a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) to mark the build result as `NOT_BUILT`. I think that's a better solution, since you won't need to add the `when` expression on each stage.

Also, the code of the pipeline looks cleaner:

```
pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('prepare') { steps { ciSkip action: 'check' } }
    // other stages here ...
  }
  post { always { ciSkip action: 'postProcess' } }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140255/how-to-get-the-git-latest-commit-message-and-prevent-the-jenkins-build-if-the-co#answer-45968194) for the code of the library.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a `skip-ci` check in one stage using [`when`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) directive. For example:

```
stages {
    stage("Check Preconditions") {
        when {
            expression {
                result = sh (script: "git log -1 | grep '.*\\[ci skip\\].*'", returnStatus: true) # Check if commit message contains skip ci label
                result == 0 # Evaluate the result
            }
        }
        steps {
            script {
                echo 'Got skip=ci, aborting build' # Just an info message
                currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED' # Mark the current build as aborted
                error('Skip-CI') # Here you actually stop the build
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Test") {
        ...
    }
```

The idea is that if you meet `skip-ci` condition the code under `when` block will be executed and the build will be aborted.

A few notes here:

- pipeline still will be marked in red color, but in the Build History you 
  will see grey (aborted) build
- If you're using a Groovy sandbox, you need to approve signature `staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String` via [In-process script approval](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/) in order to get `currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'` work

**P.S** This works well if you need to mark the build as aborted. Basically, Jenkins do abort the build on `[ci skip]` condition, so this status looks more appropriate. I assume, this will work with `currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'` as well. Otherwise, you can try to use [`catchError`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-catcherror-code-catch-error-and-set-build-result) directive

Answer (score 0):

The declarative method to do this is as follows:

```
    stage ("Unit tests") {
        when {
            not {
                changelog '.*\\[ci skip\\].*'
            }
        }
        steps {
            ...
        }
    }
```