# How to skip build for certain words in git log

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have multibranch pipeline that is created to build and run test for every Pull Request.
I would like to skip build process for commits that have certain keywords in the log

For eg: if logs are as follows for 3 commits (PR1, PR2, PR3) --

PR1 - (style) New Style added

PR2 - (docs) Updated Doc

PR3 - (test) New Test Added

Then build should be triggered only for PR3 and not for PR1 and PR2

This is because "(style)" and "(docs)" are the keywords that need to skip building process.

I tried to use the option suggested over here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140255/how-to-get-the-git-latest-commit-message-and-prevent-the-jenkins-build-if-the-co)

Particularly option of **changelog**. Here is how I implemented the code to skip words "(style)" and "(docs)" in the log.

```
stage('Deploy And Run Unit Tests') {
    when {
        not {
           changelog '.*^\\((style|docs)\\) .+$'
        }
    }
    steps {
        script { mydockerscripts.runScriptInDocker('./build_and_run_test.sh') }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to help.
Any thoughts what is wrong here in my code.

*(If it is of any use our code is in bitbucket)*

Comment: "changelog" is not relevant to your case. We use Github and we invoke GitHub API to get PR title and parse it.

Comment: as I mentioned code is in bitbucket and not github.

Comment: ok this wont work as first commit has no changelog. So definitely some other way to achieve this is needed

Comment: You should use BitBucket API in order to "get PR title and parse it".