# Best practice to set Jenkins build status?

Tags: jenkins

I see a few options to control the status of a Jenkins job, notably those two:

- Just failing with `error "Error reason"`, or throwing an exception
- Setting `currentBuild` status like `currentBuild.rawBuild.@result = hudson.model.Result.FAILURE`

What I'd like to know or understand is which of those is supposedly more common, which one should I use? As I understood, manipulating `currentBuild` might be useful when marking builds as "unstable" or reverting the state from "failure" to "pass" (though I'm not sure why would one want to do so...).

But I'm quite sure that in majority of "usual" cases error or exception should do the trick, it's easier to follow, visible in the logs. If one wants to ignore it - `try-catch` is here to help. Can someone give some motivation why would I want to use `currentBuild` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a major difference: `error` is a declarative step that stops the build with an error and custom message, while `currentBuild.rawBuild.@result = hudson.model.Result.FAILURE` is a Groovy call that could only be done within a `script` block (when running a declarative pipeline) and doesn't allow to set an explanation for the failure. Moreover, it will likely require a script approval prior to being run, so I doubt it can be recommended for general use, not to say declared as the best practice.

It's important to mention that there is another way to control the build status - `currentBuild.result` variable. It just sets the build status and doesn't stop the build immediately, allowing you to perform some actions afterwards. With it, you can't simply *revert* the status, by the way - Jenkins will not allow to make the build status better than it was, it can only get worse.

This fact leads us to the real use case for `currentBuild.rawBuild.@result` - override the build status if it's worse than you need: [How to manipulate the build result of a Jenkins pipeline job (back to 'SUCCESS')?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38221836/16417367)

So, since Jenkins does not promote the best practices in this regard, I would take the [KISS principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) as the best practice and sort the list of options based on complexity and safety/reliability:

1. `error` step is a general go-to solution - simple, safe, provides minimal but enough customization via `message` parameter, doesn't require script blocks;
2. `currentBuild.result` variable override - a bit more complex as it requires a `script` block in case of a declarative pipeline, safe as it doesn't allow to accidentally make the build status better and doesn't require admin script approval, can be combined with `error` to make the build `ABORTED`, `UNSTABLE`, or `NOT_BUILT`;
3. Exceptions - too complex for a pipeline, make more sense in shared libraries and can be dangerous if one decides to use `try-catch` within a pipeline as it's one of the "best" ways to mask the real cause of a failure and confuse everyone;
4. `currentBuild.rawBuild.@result` - the last resort option that may require admin script approval and definitely requires a clear understanding of what you're doing.

Comment: We're using always scripted pipelines, so there is no `script` blocks aka "everything is script" :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of the differences between `currentBuild.result` and `currentBuild.rawBuild.@result`, the latter was just closer to copy-paste, I'd treat them somehow the same for the context of my question. But thanks for noting anyway!

Comment: What do you mean by "exceptions are too complex"? How else would one do e.g. "post steps", like notifications in case of failure, or cleanup, or some extra reporting? When I'm looking into our code, it's absolutely trivial and we use either `try-catch` or `try-finally` all the time.

Comment: @TheGodfather it's because of the scripted pipelines. Declarative ones are around for 5-7+ years, Jenkins documentation offers them by default, and there is a dedicated [`post`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) block that allows to automatically run different actions for any build status (including complex conditions like changing of the build weather). In fact, this makes manual build status controlling a very rare action that is not expected in most pipelines.