# How to throw exception in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have handled the Jenkins pipeline steps with try catch blocks. I want to throw an exception manually for some cases. but it shows the below error.

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.IOException java.lang.String
```

I checked the scriptApproval section and there is no pending approvals.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If you want to abort your program on exception, you can use pipeline step `error` to stop the pipeline execution with an error. Example :

```
try {
  // Some pipeline code
} catch(Exception e) {
   // Do something with the exception 

   error "Program failed, please read logs..."
}
```

If you want to stop your pipeline with a success status, you probably want to have some kind of boolean indicating that your pipeline has to be stopped, e.g:

```
boolean continuePipeline = true
try {
  // Some pipeline code
} catch(Exception e) {
   // Do something with the exception 

   continuePipeline = false
   currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
}

if(continuePipeline) {
   // The normal end of your pipeline if exception is not caught. 
}
```

Comment: I don't want to abort my pipeline with failure status. I want to abort my pipeline with success status, so I would like to handle the throw option to achieve this in the catch. Is it possible to abort the pipeline with success status?

Comment: I edited my post accordingly. If that's not what you are looking for, please provide more details in your initial question, like code samples.

Comment: Exactly, I have done the same solution in my code:-)

Comment: Using the `error` step is not always ideal, as it will skip the rest of the pipeline. It's the equivalent of using `sys.exit()` in python, or `process.exit()` in Node.

Comment: Is it possible to RETRY the failed stage which failed earlier due to some error ?!

Comment: @Prathameshdhanawade See [Sample of Jenkinsfile for retry block.](https://gist.github.com/daipresents/c7f982ffce9c1bda73b4387d6b1ae3da#file-jenkinsfile). (Fun fact: a comment to this Gist links to exactly this question here.)

Answer (score 31):

This is how I do it in Jenkins 2.x.

Notes: Do not use the error signal, it will skip any post steps.

```
stage('stage name') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def status = someFunc() 

                    if (status != 0) {
                        // Use SUCCESS FAILURE or ABORTED
                        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
                        throw new Exception("Throw to stop pipeline")
                        // do not use the following, as it does not trigger post steps (i.e. the failure step)
                        // error "your reason here"

                    }
                }
            }
            post {
                success {
                    script {
                        echo "success"
                    }
                }
                failure {
                    script {
                        echo "failure"
                    }
                }
            }            
        }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It seems no other type of exception than `Exception` can be thrown. No `IOException`, no `RuntimeException`, etc.

Comment: Note, at least in the current version, the post steps are executed indeed even if you fail with error().

Comment: setting `currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"` does not work for me here; it still drops into the `post.failure` block.

Comment: throw new Exception doesn't work for me, constructor does't seem to exist for 1 argument as string: `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Exception.call() is applicable for argument types: : (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl)`

Comment: That's because I was throwing the exception from within a class. Groovy is so stupid, why can't it know all types within a class...

Comment: If this isn't true any longer, I suggest to add a note in the answer, because otherwise it's misleading.

Answer (score 19):

It seems no other type of exception than `Exception` can be thrown. No `IOException`, no `RuntimeException`, etc.

This will work:

```
throw new Exception("Something went wrong!")
```

But these won't:

```
throw new IOException("Something went wrong!")
throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong!")
```

Comment: You can use IOException(String) indeed if you approve it from the permission panel.   Whether that's useful is a different question.

Comment: This used to work for me, but lately I have been getting `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.lang.Exception`

Comment: for not permitter to use please go to jenkins configuration “in-process script approval” 
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/script-approval/ and approve there

Answer (score 1):

I used .jenkinsfile.
I did it in the following way:

```
    stage('sample') {
        steps {
            script{
                try{
                    bat '''sample.cmd'''
                    RUN_SAMPLE_RESULT="SUCCESS"
                    echo "Intermediate build result: ${currentBuild.result}"
                }//try
                catch(e){
                    RUN_SAMPLE_RESULT="FAILURE"
                    echo "Intermediate build result: ${currentBuild.result}"
                    // normal error handling
                    throw e
                }//catch
            }//script
        }//steps
    }//stage
```

Based on value of RUN_SAMPLE_RESULT you can design post build action.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to get it to exit with an ABORTED status like this:

```
node('mynode') {

    stage('Some stage') {
    
        currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
        error('Quitting')
    }
}
```

The same does not work when setting currentBuild.result to 'SUCCESS', though.  For that, you need a try-catch with a flag like the answer from Pom12.